# How can we dynamicaly implement Insert Column in ContextMenu of Syncfusion Treegrid?

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

How can we implement Insert Column in ContextMenu of Syncfusion Treegrid?
Insert Column
Rename Column
Delete Column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have achieved your requirement using Custom Contextmenu feature of the TreeGrid and handled the Insert, Delete and Rename the columns by following the steps below:

1. We have placed the new Item as Custom Context menu Item if we want to display in header we need to use .e-headercontent class as target along with text and id properties and using ContextMenuClick events we have performed Insert, Delete and Rename columns.
2. To perform Insert/delete/Rename actions, we have pushed/splice the columns into columns property and refresh the columns using refreshColumns method.

Refer to the below code:

App.Component.html:

```
<ejs-treegrid #treegrid
                  [dataSource]="data"
                  height="400"
                  childMapping="subtasks"
                  [treeColumnIndex]="1"
                  [contextMenuItems]="contextMenuItems"
                  (contextMenuClick)="contextMenuClick($event)">
        <e-columns>
            <e-column field="taskID"
                      headerText="Task ID"
                      width="80"
                      textAlign="Right"
                      editType="numericedit"></e-column>
        </e-columns>
           .      .     .
 </ejs-treegrid>
```

App.Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public data: Object[] = [];
  @ViewChild('treegrid')
  public treegrid: TreeGridComponent;
  public contextMenuItems: Object;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = sampleData;
    this.contextMenuItems = [
      { text: 'Insert Column', target: '.e-headercontent', id: 'insert' },
      { text: 'Delete Column', target: '.e-headercontent', id: 'delete' },
      { text: 'Rename Column', target: '.e-headercontent', id: 'rename' },
    ];
  }

  contextMenuClick(args?: MenuEventArgs): void {
    if (args.item.id === 'insert') {
      let columnName = { field: 'priority', width: 100 };
      this.treegrid.columns.push(columnName); // Insert Columns
      this.treegrid.refreshColumns(); // Refresh Columns
    } else if (args.item.id === 'delete') {
      let columnName = 2;
      this.treegrid.columns.splice(columnName, 1); //Splice columns
      this.treegrid.refreshColumns(); //Refresh Columns
    } else if (args.item.id === 'rename') {
      this.treegrid.getColumnByField('taskName'); //Get the required column
      this.treegrid.getColumnByField('taskName').headerText = 'Task details'; //Rename column name
      this.treegrid.refreshColumns(); //Refresh Columns
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Link:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grs5bm?file=app.component.ts

API link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/treegrid/#refreshcolumns

Documentation Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/bootstrap5/treegrid/custom-contextmenu
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/treegrid/context-menu/#custom-context-menu-items